# Jquery How to check if server is online ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to check via Javascript if server is online to show on client if server is offline an alert. Something like Gmail does when the client web interface lose connection to server.

I can do an AJAX request each 5 seconds (hearbeat) and if the request is on error show a message but this is not a good idea because if I'm doing request to server each 5 seconds the session will never close.

How can I achive this without affecting the session timeout on server?

Comment: Look for socket.io... It may be what you need. Since their web site doesn't explain clearly what it is, check Wkipedia here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really the answer you were asking for but it might be helpful.

I am assuming that by session you are talking about an authenticated session.

If that is the case then if you have sliding expiration set to false then using polling will not extend the expiration date of the auth cookie.
 If you are using forms auth read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration(v=vs.110).aspx

If you are using Asp.Net Identity read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.slidingexpiration(v=vs.113).aspx

And if you decide that polling in ok you may want to check out [Offline Js](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline) it makes determining if your app is online a breeze.

Comment: Offline JS was a very good discover for me. It works perfectly. I will put a snipet here as soon as I can. Thanks for your help

Comment: I cannot add my code because the question is closed

Comment: @JuanDYB First, you will need to edit your question with some code so it can be approved as a valid question. Then you are free to go \o